# Android EditText default style

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show a EditText with the classic layout showing the full textbox, not only the bottom line. In the layout editor I can see it so, but when running the app it is showing only the bottom line. I am using `android:Theme.Light` for the app. How could I change this?

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: the edittext is just a 9patch image so all your have to do is change the image so what you want it to look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//You can try this one it works for me

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#00000000" />    
<stroke android:width="2.5dp" 
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners
android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>     
Then use this shape for the edit text widget inside an activity xml file as required:

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/searchBox"        
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
     android:hint="@string/Search"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" >

 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try solution with this solution

```
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#E7E7E7"
    android:height="10dp"/>

<corners
    android:radius="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import an image box as a drawable, and then set it as a background like this.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textinput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebox"/>
```

With this, the imagebox will be placed under your text box, and the underline will dissapear.